# Seamless mobile redirect script

Tags: javascript, mobile-website

I have developed a mobile version of an existing web site.  I have added some JavaScript to the home page of the desktop version of the site to handle the redirect.  The code works on a mobile device except that a copy of the home page appears before the redirect.  Can anyone help with this or does anyone know how to make the JavaScript run before the page loads?  An example of the JavaScript code is below.

Also, the site's desktop home page is in HTML and PHP is not an option.  We also don't want to do a permanent mobile redirect.  We want users to be able to access the desktop version if they want.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<!--start JavaScript code-->
<script>
  if (screen.width < 500 ||
     navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
     navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
     navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
     navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
     navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/) ||
     navigator.appName("Chrome")) {
      window.location.replace("TexasLandBankMobile/default.html");

</script>
<!--end JavaScript code-->

<title>Test</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    This is not a mobile device <br/>
</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use reactive design and don't send mobile users anywhere but your homepage?

And unless you do the redirect on the server level (apache rewrite etc) you can't do what you ask.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  We don't have time to implement reactive design.  Is there a way to implement on the server level but allow mobile users to go to the desktop version if they desire.

Comment: @RobertDavis Yes, when you do your redirect on your server, have it look for a query string in the url like `?desktop=true` and for a `desktop=true` cookie.  If that flag is set, set the `desktop=true` cookie and let them through to the main site.  If the cookie is set, let them through to the main site.  On your main site have a links that says "mobile version" which deletes the cookie and redirects them to the mobile version

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to redirect the user before they even get to your page, that way the user doesn't have to wait for a bloated desktop version of the site to download.

But for a workaround, you could try hiding both versions of the page and then set the desktop/mobile version of the site to visible.

e.g.

```
<script>

function isMobileDevice() {
    return screen.width < 500 ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
        navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/) ||
        navigator.appName("Chrome"));
}

if (isMobileDevice()) {
  window.location.replace("TexasLandBankMobile/default.html");
} else {
  // set container div to visible
  document.getElementById('container').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
}

</script>
```